# CBCentralManager not getting connected

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect near by bluetooth devices. I'm able to discover but i'm unable to connect them.

this delegate is working but after discovering i'm trying connect with one of the pheripheral

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        if let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? String {
            print(device)
            if device.contains("BODY") {
                self.connectPeripheral = peripheral
                self.connectPeripheral.delegate = self
                self.manager.connect(connectPeripheral, options: nil)
               self.manager.stopScan()
            }
        }
    }
```

These two delegates methods are not invoking. one of these should be called.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    } 



func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    //NSLog("Error %@", error.debugDescription)
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

Comment: Have you been connected to it yet and just stopped debugging? It's bluetooth. Be prepared with inconsistent states on your devices ;-) Try to switch off your bluetooth on both devices, switch them back onh (what also helps is to "forget this device" and wait 5 seconds until you turn your bluetooth back on. Do never ever just stop debbuging without disconnecting from your bluetooth connection, else the peripheral might be in a wrong state and does not know it is not connected anymore. We implemented heart beat functionality for this, which reads or populates every n seconds a characteristic.

Comment: I debugged as you said. It's no use. I think it's swift 3.0 syntax issue. Those delegates methods are not getting executed at all.

Comment: Do you have a singleton instance of your CoreBluetooth and NO iBeacons scanning with CLLocation (iBeacons are used with CoreLocation but do also require Bluetooth) running in background?

Comment: @Lepidopteron I'm not using singleton for CoreBluetooth. I'm not using iBeacon also. May be other apps were using.

Comment: Other Apps are no problem. It is just important for your implementation to have only one instance taking care of the CoreBluetooth functionality

Comment: Right now i'm testing this on sample project which contains only one view controller. I'm only using one instance for this.

Comment: i got same issue after update to ios 11. my codes work properly on ios 10.

Comment: I too got same issue after iOS 11.0

Comment: I have seen this issue too, but not consistently.

Answer (score 3):

You need to maintain a strong reference to the CBPeripheral instance, because once you tell the Central to stop scanning, it will deallocate all its discovered peripherals.

Comment: This is not the root issue here, seems related to Settings -> BT connection state.